# Truncating trailing zeros for ios 5.x and 6.x

Tags: ios5, ios6

In ios 5.X and 6.X , for input type="number" if I enter a number having decimal point followed by single digit followed by zeros,then the trailing zeros are truncated.

I want the entered number to be displayed as it is,the way I enter.

ex: If I enter the number as xxx.x00 then it should be displayed as xxx.x00 in the text box.
Currently its displayed as xxx.x

Please tell me the solution if any, I am new to ios.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input type="tel"` will give you the result you're after on iPad on IOS 6.X at least. `tel` uses *almost* the exact same keyboard as `number`, and does not have the truncate-trailing-zeroes issue.

Unfortunately this isn't a good experience on the iPhone, which really does use the dialer keyboard with no decimal point symbol available.